# Standard Representation of a von Neumann algebra associated with a character

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Suppose that $\Gamma$ is a discrete group. For an extremal character $\tau$ on $\Gamma$, we denote by $M$ the corresponding GNS vNa (which is a tracial factor). This is a consequence of a well-known theorem of Thomma which says the following:

Theorem (Thomma) Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete group. There is a one to one
correspondence between:

1. Equivalence classes of unitary representations $\pi : \Gamma \to \mathcal{U}(M)$, where $M$ is a finite von Neumann algebra with a given normal faithful trace $\tau$ , and such that $\pi(\Gamma)'' = M$, and
2. Characters $\phi : \Gamma \to \mathbb{C}$, which is given by $\phi(g) = \tau(\pi(g))$.

Moreover, $M$ is a factor if and only if $\phi$ is
an extreme point in the space of characters.

I have a question about the standard form of a von Neumann algebra $M$ (obtained from an extremal character via the GNS construction). Using the Theorem of Thomma we know that $(M,\tau)$ is a tracial von Neumann algebra, $\tau$ is a faithful normal trace on $M$. Now, if we do the GNS construction of $M$ again with respect to $\tau$ (via the inner product $\langle x,y\rangle=\tau(y^*x))$, we obtain a representation $\pi_{\tau}$, a separable Hilbert space $L^2(M)$ and a cyclic vector $\xi_{\tau}$.

Define $J: \pi_{\tau}(M)(\xi_{\tau})\to L^2(M)$ by $J(\pi_{\tau}(x)\xi_{\tau})=\pi_{\tau}(x^*)\xi_{\tau}$. Observe that for all $x,y \in M$, we have
\begin{align*}\langle J(\pi_{\tau}(x)\xi_{\tau}),J(\pi_{\tau}(y)\xi_{\tau})\rangle&=\langle\pi_{\tau}(x^*)\xi_{\tau}, \pi_{\tau}(y^*)\xi_{\tau}\rangle\\&=\tau(yx^*)\\&=\tau(x^*y)\\&=\langle (\pi_{\tau}(y)\xi_{\tau}),(\pi_{\tau}(x)\xi_{\tau})\rangle\end{align*}
Hence, $J$ is a conjugate linear unitary with $J^2=1$.

Question: If $JMJ=M'$, then every $T\in B(L^2(M))$ which commutes with $J\pi(g)J$ must be in M?

My thinking was that if $J\pi(g)JT=TJ\pi(g)J$, then $JxJT=TJxJ$ for all
$x\in\text{Span}\left\{\pi(g):g\in \Gamma\right\}$ and hence, $T\in (JMJ)'=(M)''=M$.

Is this correct?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking, since $J$ and $M$ don't act on the same space (so $JMJ$ makes no sense).

Comment: I should say that I am identifying $M$ with $\pi_{\tau}(M)$.

Comment: In that case, the answer to your question is yes. But you don't need all the introduction, your reasoning applied to any von Neumann algebra in standard form.

Comment: Also, is it the case that $JMJ$ is metrizable seen inside $L^2(M))$?

Comment: A subset of a metric space is metrizable by definition, so not sure what you mean.

Comment: Thank you, I see now.